# Skipping Tokens which are part of ANTLR4 Grammar

Tags: antlr4

In ANTLR4 this will cause the LINE_FOLD token to be skipped:

```
LINE_FOLD
 : CRLF WSP -> skip
 ;
```

But if I do this:

```
ESCAPED_CHAR
 : '\\' LINE_FOLD? '\\'
 | '\\' LINE_FOLD? ';'
 | '\\' LINE_FOLD? ','
 | '\\' LINE_FOLD? N
 ;
```

will it return the ESCAPED_CHAR without the LINE_FOLD, and if not how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, inside `ESCAPED_CHAR`, `CRLF WSP` will not be `skip`ped.

ANTLR(4) best-practice is to handle such target specific actions in the stage after parsing (in a listener or visitor).

However, you *can* add a target specific block at the end of your rule that discards the `\\ CRLF WSP` from the `ESCAPED_CHAR` rule:

```
ESCAPED_CHAR
 : '\\' LINE_FOLD? [\\;,nN] 
   {
     String s = getText();
     setText(s.substring(s.length() - 1));
   }
 ;
```

Assuming your lexer rule `N` matches either `'n'` or `'N'`.

Now the rule `ESCAPED_CHAR` will only produce tokens whose contents will be on of: `\\`, `;`, `,`, `n`, or `N`.

Needles to say, this will only work with the Java target.

Comment: So if I want to stick with ANTLR4 best practice and put this in a listener (as I've built out with listeners so far), how would I go about working my way through the contexts to find my escaped chars and tweak them accordingly?  I have a TextContext which contains various tokens in it...

Comment: I'm afraid there's not much more than manually replacing these characters using the target language's built-in string methods, AFAIK. You may want to prune the [ANTLR discussion-group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/antlr-discussion) to see if there is (or was) a discussion about doing such things. And if not, you could start one :)